# Will my laptop support a fullHD external monitor?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution, vga

I have an HP (previously Compaq) CQ40 laptop with a VGA port. It has a maximum display resolution of 1200x800.
I'm thinking of buying an external monitor and connect to it using the VGA port. The monitor's maximum resolution is 1920x1080. Will my laptop be able to drive this monitor?
Here are the details I found about the video adapter:

- Chip type - Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset family
- DAC type - internal,
- Adapter string - Mobile Intel(R) GMA 4500M

Answer (score 0):

I have one running with a FullHD monitor. You are aware it won't work for gaming or for old games you will have to lower resolution. I also have some problems with youtube videos from time to time but that is mostly the entire old computer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I plan to use it for web browsing (stock charts mainly) and some excel related tasks. No gaming at all.